# Automate Log In on Website (Autofill and Submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to visit a website and log in automatically.

After this, I want to return whether or not this was a success or failure, but I can't get it to work. The page loads blank and nothing happens.

Note: I have deliberately greyed out the URL.

Below is my attempt,

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<TITLE>Login</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            runLogin();
        });

    function runLogin(){
        alert("start");

        if (window.location.indexOf("url") > -1) {
                jQuery("#j_username").val("username");
                jQuery("#j_password").val("password");
                jQuery("#loginForm").submit();
            }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to log-in this way?

Comment: What kind of data is returned by the back-end login script? Does it return HTML, JSON, XML, or plain text?

Comment: What is `window.location.indexOf("url")` supposed to do? Is that the part where you grayed out the url?

Comment: -Akshay I essentially want to visit a website and then log in to simply confirm that it is 'running as it should be'. -4castle I don't actually think anything is returned and yes the 'url' part will be replaced with the URL I am testing.

Comment: I looked it up, and `j_security_check` returns the HTML of the login page if the login fails, and it returns the HTML of the page which sent the request if it succeeds. Are you using `j_security_check`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your login form, use Protractor or other e2e test framework, but this way does not seem very safe.

[http://angular.github.io/protractor/](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/)

Answer (score 0):

It's loading a blank page because your back-end script isn't redirecting back to the page you started on. **One option** is to send the current webpage URL as an extra field to the login form so that it can redirect back after it has logged in. This will require you to refactor your back-end code so that it can handle this extra information (not really possible if you're using `j_security_check`). **Another option** is to make an AJAX request to your login page so that it doesn't actually redirect the page, it just submits the form quietly and then JS handles the response.

If you want to add the URL of the current page to the login request, do this:

```
function runLogin() {
    if (window.location.indexOf("url") > -1) {
            jQuery("#j_username").val("username");
            jQuery("#j_password").val("password");
            jQuery("#loginForm").append(
                '<input type="hidden" name="url" value="'+window.location.href+'"/>'
            );
            jQuery("#loginForm").submit();
    }
}
```

If you want to use AJAX to send a login request:

```
function runLogin() {
    var $form = $("#loginForm");
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(data) {
        // login successful/unsuccessful message displays
        // depending on what "data" contains
    });
}
```

Comment: This was my thinking also, as from the information you have given I will attempt to use ajax instead as this is closer to what I was trying to achieve in the first instance. My only issue is, how do I actually submit the form on the web page. The said form is indeed #loginForm, but how do I fill the individual fields using an ajax request?

Comment: Look up jQuery's `.serialize()` function and `$.post` function. It converts forms into query strings. It's what I used in my example.

Comment: Also look up `$.post`. It takes a url, a query string, and a callback function and submits it. When the submit completes, it runs the callback function.